# Python. Регулярные выражения. html

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup, re

Всем здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сообразить следующее, но не получается.
У меня есть вот такой html код:

```
<td data="2020-09-28T07:10:10Z">
    "   7 hr 21 min -  "
<\td>
```

И у каждого столбца 'data' меняется. Я хотел бы сделать поиск по регулярному выражению. Как я могу это сделать? Я пытался делать следующее:

```
soup = get_html('https://my-link.com')
table = soup.find('tr', id='jobs')
my_job = table.find_all('td', data=r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z')
```

Но не получается, поэтому помогите пожалуйста. Тэгов 'td' там в данном случае много, но не у всех есть 'data'. Но Некоторые встречаются, где 'data="0"'

Comment: Поиск чего именно?

Comment: текста внутри тега "  7 hr 21 min -  "

Comment: @Эникейщик но я и сам тег не могу найти для начала

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю стоит использовать парсер xml либо модуль re:

Либо же, если использование bs4 обязательно то

```
data='''
<html><head><title>a title</title></head><body><td data="2020-09-28T07:10:10Z">
    "   7 hr 21 min -  "
<\td></body></html>
'''
import re
alist=re.findall('<td data=\"[A-Z0-9\-\:]*\">[\r\n\t\"\ \-A-z0-9]*<\\td>',data)
#['<td data="2020-09-28T07:10:10Z">\n    "   7 hr 21 min -  "\n<\td>']
import bs4, soupsieve
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup (data, 'html.parser')
alist=soup.find_all(['td'])
for it in alist:
    if it.has_attr('data'):
        it
        '''
        <td data="2020-09-28T07:10:10Z">
    "   7 hr 21 min -  "
&lt;    d&gt;</td>
'''
    else:
        'not find'
```

Регулярка здесь составлена неудачно, но работает- не силён я в этом.
По bs4 идёт поиск всех элементов, затем проверка наличия атрибута.

Comment: а что надо вместо 'tag' поставить? у мена данной переменной нет.

Comment: `def getSuccessAndDuration(self, project, job):
        soup = self.get_html('https://my-link/view/' + project)
        table = soup.find('tr', id='job_'+job)
        print(soupsieve.filter('td:and(data)', [soup, tag]))
        # success = re.findall(r'(\d+\w+)', table.find_all('td')[6].text.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '').replace('-log', ''))[0]
        # duration = table.find_all('td', data='0')[0].text

        # return (success, duration)`

Comment: как мне обращаться и находить данную структуру? Ибо data тег меняется. Поэтому я и хотел, чтоб он универсально искал по регулярному выражению название тега

Comment: Я пытаюсь использовать одновременно и re и bs4. Но у меня не выходит

Comment: обновил код выше